# how to link to other website with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I'm new to codeIgniter. Can you tell me, how to link to other website url in codeIgniter?

I tired to do like this:

```
 <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
```

But instead it gives me this

```
 <a href="localhost/site-name/www.googlel.com">google</a>
```

It always refers to the base `url`, even though I don't `echo base_url();` on the `href`.

Thanks

Comment: Always Use http:// or https:// ... Other wise CI  understand it's as a controller function. Try to finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating links to external pages, you must prefix the URL with either http:// or https:// , like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Technically this has little to do with CodeIgniter, but a difference between relative and absolute URLs.

If you did want to use CodeIgniter to generate the link, do this:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
echo anchor('http://www.google.com', 'Google');
```